# Подгрузка в ListView

Tags: android, listview

Вообщем реализовую подгрузку данных в список. Создал AsynTask который принимает на вход число с которого надо начинать извлекать данные. Реализовал слушатель

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount) {
    boolean loadMore = firstVisible + visibleCount >= totalCount;

    if (loadMore && loadingTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
        loadingTask = new LoadMoreAsyncTask();
        loadingTask.execute(totalCount);
    }
}
```

А вот как реализовать адаптер не знаю. Сейчас он у меня в конструкторе принимает List. Я так понимаю нужно создать в адаптере метод типа add(List) который будет добавлять новые данные, возможно через .addAll но как не знаю. И ещё, где правильно присваивать адаптер списку(lv.set(adapter))? Сразу в onCreate или в AsynTask, onPostExecute.

Answer (score 2):

1. `AsynTask` нужно пересоздавать, второй раз вы не вызовите `execute`
2. Вы правильно все написали по поводу добавления, не понятно что вам не понятно

   class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

   ```
       private List<String> items;

       public ListAdapter(List<String> items) {
           this.items = items;
       }

       public void addAll(List<String> newItems){
           items.addAll(newItems);
       }

       ......
   }
   ```

не забудьте вызвать `notifyDataSetChanged();` после добавления новых элементов и обязательно в основном потоке.

3. Зачем адаптер добавлять каждый раз если можно добавлять данные в уже существующий адаптер. Просто храните ссылку на адаптер после создания и добавления его к списку

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ```
       private ListAdapter adapter;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);

           .........
           adapter = new ListAdapter(new ArrayList<String>());
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
           .........

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Сделал все, кроме вашего 1 пункта(я его не понял). Теперь проблема в onScroll. Если его убрать выводятся первые 10 записей(как и нужно) с ним же выводятся эти 10 записей 3 раза подряд, сразу, может я не верно вычисляю последнюю позицию?

Comment: С этим разобрался, извиняюсь, теперь другая проблема. В каждом последующим пакете данных в начале встречаются item с предыдущего пакета.  Допустим идёт первые 10 записей потом 11, потом девятая или десятая потом далее 12,13 и т.д. до 20 потом 21,20 или 19 и далее 22,23. Может проблема в неверном определении последней позиции?